# Symfony Doctrine Many-To-Many fetching data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

I have `MoneyChanger` Entity which has Many-To-Many relationship with `AddTransaction` entity.

I want to get all rows from `AddTransaction` Entity that belongs to `MoneyChanger` Entity.

Here are the structures of my tables.

`MoneyChanger` tbl

```
id  | created_at
----------------
1   | 2017-08-28 
2   | 2017-08-28 
3   | 2017-08-28
```

`money_changer_add_transaction` tbl

```
money_changer_id: |  add_transaction_id
---------------------------------------
       1          |       1
---------------------------------------
       1          |       2
---------------------------------------
       1          |       3
---------------------------------------
       2          |       4
---------------------------------------
       3          |       5
```

`add_transaction` tbl

```
id
---
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here's what I've done so far, but I got no luck.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $repository = $em->getRepository('MontealBundle:MoneyChanger');
            $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                   ->where('p.createdAt BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
                   ->andWhere('p.type = :type')
                   ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
                   ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
                   ->setParameter('type', $type)
                   ->getQuery();

            $records = $query->getResult();

            foreach ($records as $record) {

                echo "</b>".$record->getId()."</b></br>";

                $transactions = $em->getRepository('MontealBundle:AddTransaction');
                $qry = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->innerJoin('a.money_changer_add_transaction', 'm')
                    ->where('a.money_changer_id = :money_changer_id')
                    ->setParameter('money_changer_id', $record->getId())
                    ->getQuery();

                $transactions = $qry->getResult();

                dump($transactions);

                foreach ($transactions as $trans) {
                   echo "</b>".$trans->getId()."</b></br>"; 
                }
            }
```

Here's the MoneyChanger Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="money_changer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MontealBundle\Repository\MoneyChangerRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class MoneyChanger
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AddTransaction", inversedBy="moneyChanger", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="money_changer_add_transaction",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="money_changer_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="add_transaction_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *   )
     */
    private $addTransaction;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addTransaction = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Here's the `AddTransaction` Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="add_transaction")
 */
class AddTransaction 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MoneyChanger", mappedBy="addTransaction", cascade={"persist"})
     *  
     */
    private $moneyChanger;

     public function __construct(){
        $this->moneyChanger = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Error:

`Class MontealBundle\Entity\MoneyChanger has no association named money_changer_add_transaction`

Comment: Which error do you retrieve? What do you expect and what you retrieve?

Comment: I got this error `Class MontealBundle\Entity\MoneyChanger has no association named money_changer_add_transaction`

Comment: please show us the entity MoneyChanger please

Comment: I update my codes above please check thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$qry = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
     ->innerJoin('a.addTransaction', 'm')
     ->where('a.id = :money_changer_id')
     ->setParameter('money_changer_id', $record->getId())
     ->getQuery();
```

Comment: I'm not getting the id from AddTransaction table. 
What I want to get is the row from moneyChanger then the row from addTransaction if it has record. 

the row that i am getting is still from money_changer

Comment: try with a leftJoin please @phpmeter

Comment: I still get the record from `money_changer` tbl.

Answer (score 0):

To get the related transactions for your `MoneyChanger` object your first query builder is fine which gives you `MoneyChanger` objects when you loop through these records there is no need to run query builder again to fetch the related `AddTransaction` objects because each `MoneyChanger` object will have a collection of related `AddTransaction` objects, you only need to call the getter method and loop through on `AddTransaction` objects like

```
$records = $query->getResult();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    /* your other code */
    $transactions = $record->getAddTransaction();
    foreach ($transactions as $trans) {
        echo "</b>".$trans->getId()."</b></br>"; 
    }

}
```

Also make sure your `MoneyChanger` class should have the below method, which will have an `ArrayCollection` of related `AddTransaction` objects

```
public function getAddTransaction()
{
    return $this->addTransaction;
}
```

Reference [**5.9. Many-To-Many, Bidirectional**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)